# Customize page-header area default theme in Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-boost, moodle-theme

I am using the default Boost theme and want to add some text beside the logo in the page-header section.

I have tried doing so in the Additional HTML in Within HEAD, but does not add the text in that area.

I am on version 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

The HEAD is before the BODY in HTML so isn't displayed.

You could add the text to "When BODY is opened" (additionalhtmltopofbody)

Via Site admin > Appearance > Additional HTML

Or direct to /admin/settings.php?section=additionalhtml

Anything you enter there will be displayed at the top of the page.

Comment: When BODY is opened, puts the text in the MAIN region below the image. I want to add text next to the Logo in the page-header section.